# How to convert string values from variable to HTML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**How to change string values to HTML in Javascript.**

**ISSUE**

My form renders HTML code as a string, which i don't have a control.

it is rendering dynamically.

### Now i need to change that string content to render as HTML

I have these following values in var **checking** as a string

```
var checking = formEl.innerHTML;
```

String values in var **checking**  are

```
 <thead id="updateContent">
  <tr>
    <th style="width:25%" class="spacingInHeader">Years of Expierence </th>
    <th style="width:50%" class="spacingInHeader">Salary</th>
    <th style="width:25%" class="spacingInHeader">Actions</th>
    <input type="hidden" id="editRowIndex" value="">    
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr id="divUserList">
    <td class="dynamicRow"> <input style="width:100px!important;" type="text" id="totalExperience"> </td>
    <td class="dynamicRow"> <input type="text" id="salaryForThisPosition"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="alf-id29">
    <td style="border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(197, 197, 197);">1</td>
    <td style="border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(197, 197, 197);">1</td>
    <td style="border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(197, 197, 197);"><a class="addLink" style="margin-right:10px" href="#" onclick="javascript:editRow(this);return false;"> Edit </a> <a href="#" class="addLink" onclick="javascript:deleteRow(this);return false;"> Delete </a> </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

i want to render these string values as HTML

**More Explanation**

### i have values in **checking** variable

In that string values, i have a id **updateContent**, i want to render these string values as HTML

Is there any way i can achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you @Denys Séguret, but this is the problem i am facing, code is too big to post here, so i have taken sample code.

Comment: Read that page, you'll see it doesn't suggest you post the whole code

Comment: @Denys Séguret , Can you please help me to make my question clear, my problem is my form renders HTML code as a text, which i don't have a control. Now i need to change that text content to render as HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your html you want to change inside another div. And change that div's inner html

For Example if we have a very simple code of this:

```
<p>Hello~!</p>
```

And you want to use html to be able to modify it freely to say...

```
<h1>Goodbye?!</h1>
```

What you do is simple: you put it inside a div like this:

```
<div id="myName"><p>Hello~!</p></div>
```

and you do this in your javascript:

```
document.getElementById("myName").innerHTML = "<h1>Goodbye?!</h1>"
```

Thats... about it really!

JsFiddle for those who want to check: https://jsfiddle.net/9az241sf/

Comment: Can you please provide me the sample code, it will be much help,

Comment: Done. Also read from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML that if you are reading the value then you must pay attention to special characters such as "<" Since they appear as a special character (e.g. &lt )

Comment: I have tried your solution, but unfortunately it is not working, i have updated the question, please have a look

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Also I still can't find the part you are trying to change the html of. I don't exactly get your specific issue here.

Comment: sorry, if i am not clear to you, i want to change the id "updateContent" to HTML, actually now it is a string.

Comment: Did you try putting the entire thing inside a new div and tried modifying that div's inner html? What kind of issue happened if that failed? DId nothing happen?

Comment: Can you write down your javascript then? I think the problem isn't in your html because there is no logical way for nothing to happen unless the js is dying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118448/discussion-between-manjunath-siddappa-and-zaid-al-shattle).